# How to create a timeline view of a task list?

Tags: 2013, view, task-list

Is there a way to create a timeline view of a task list?  From my experience, you can add tasks to a timeline, but there is no way to create a view based on that timeline.  It's all or nothing it seems like.

Example to help illustrate what I'm asking for:

**My full task list with items added to timeline:**

[image]

I have two views based on the category of the tasks (*Alpha* and *Numeric*).  I would like to have a separate view of the timeline based on these two views.

**My view of the task list, with the timeline, of just my Alpha tasks:**

[image]

You can see that my task list is filtered like I want, but my timeline is not. This is what I'm trying to figure out.

I know there is a timeline web part and have tried to use this.  It seems odd that I am able to make a selection between a view from a list, but don't know how to create said view.

**My timeline web part:**

[image]

Under *View Name* you can see *Timeline* is selected.  There are no other views here to select and I don't see anything in the task list on how to create another timeline type view.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @hoffie4 I have not. The best solution I know of currently would be to use multiple lists. Not very clean, but the best that I'm aware of.

Comment: that or add an additional timeline (but that hasn't been working well)

Comment: Not sure what version of SharePoint you are running, but Microsoft Project integrates with SharePoint. Might be something in there that could help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way to add multiple time lines. The limitation on SharePoint is that for a task list, there is only one default timeline in which the tasks are added.  We can add another timeline to the list using the list folder properties. If we query the folder properties, we can find the timeline_timeline property which contains the metadata for the graph. We can also find the default timeline name.

The solution is to use JavaScript COM and clone the timeline property. You can also add JavaScript to allow the user to change the default timeline graph or just use the web properties to select the default view.  This way you can have a master timeline as well as secondary timelines.

Find more technical details in this blog.

http://www.ozkary.com/2016/06/sharepoint-2013-adding-multiple.html

Comment: I tried this out and it does work.. however, like you mention in your post, to add to each timeline you need to go into the web part properties and change the view to what timeline you want to add to before you do it.  If you switch the timeline in any list view it switches for all views in the site.  For display purposes this isn't a big deal because you can still use the standalone Timeline web part, but to add items to a specific timeline it is not user friendly.

Comment: This is the part about "add JavaScript to allow the user to change the default timeline"  Basically,  instead of having to edit the web part, we can add a drop down populated with the list of time lines. A button that allows the user to quickly switch the default timeline. This can be contained on a special view "Manage timelines". If there is interest, I can write code and an article for this.